# Gnuplot: Is it possible to skip header lines starting with a given character?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have data files where header lines begin with the ampersand "&" character. Gnuplot does not like this (using the "plot" command with these files generates an error message). One way to handle this would be to run the data files through a python program to remove the lines that begin with "&". That is fairly simple but I was wondering if there was a simple way within gnuplot itself to skip lines beginning with "&".

Added in response to @theorzh:
I am using gnuplot 4.6 and the error message is (line 2 starts with a "&"):

```
gnuplot> plot 'test'
              ^
         Bad data on line 2 of file test
```

Comment: what is your code? which version of gnuplot do you use? what is the error message? My gnuplot 5.2 ignores lines starting with`&`.

Comment: what is the reason that you stick to gnuplot 4.6 and not use 5.2... ?

Comment: > what is the reason that you stick to gnuplot 4.6 and not use 5.2... ? Answer: I do not have admin privileges to the system so unless there is a reason (and up to now there has not been any reason to), I just take what the admins have installed.

Comment: @theozh: "My gnuplot 5.2 ignores lines starting with &". Curious. I tried 5.2 patchlevel 5 and had the same problem

Comment: ok, maybe I had typed in `set datafile commentschar '&'` before and this setting was kept. So, if you type in this line or add it to your code it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the manual? Have you consulted `help`?

```
set datafile commentschar '&'
```

Comment: Great! That works. And I did check the manual under the plot command and did not find anything. The documentation on this was elsewhere.